# Any way to access the iCloud Photo Library settings using NSURL?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I know how to access iCloud settings:

```
prefs:root=CASTLE
```

And, I know iCloud Storage is:

```
prefs:root=CASTLE&path=STORAGE_AND_BACKUP
```

But, is there anyway to access Settings>iCloud>Photos?

I've already tried the following, none of them work:

```
    prefs:root=CASTLE&path=PHOTOS
    prefs:root=CASTLE&path=PHOTO_LIBRARY
    prefs:root=CASTLE&path=PHOTO_STORAGE
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, the iCloud Photo Library options are also in the Photos setting:

`prefs:root=Photos`